# Basic Node and Express: Serve Static Assets

Tags: javascript, express

```
let express = require('express');



let app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

I am trying to solve freecodecamp's "Basic Node and Express: Serve Static Assets" challenge but it keep says "not working. Could someone help me? Thanks.

This is the path folder [The main files in my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVNcm.png)

Comment: Where is your public folder exactly relative to your main.js file?

Comment: It is within the same directory actually. It is the default freecodecamp setting. I added the pic to the main post.

Comment: I was going to tell you that to serve static files in a folder you could just go to your folder and launch `npx http-server` from the terminal but then I saw that it was an exercise specifically asking to use node and express :D

Comment: Can you share more information about the node environment? Which versions are you using?

Answer (score -1):

If your public folder is whithin the same directory of your main.js file, you can use:

```
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))
```

Comment: I tried this but didnt work, I have added the directory to the original post.

Answer (score -1):

As described in express documentation:

> If you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve:

```js
const path = require('path')
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```